# Spring Data Cassandra with QueryDSL

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, spring-data-cassandra

Does spring data cassandra support QueryDSL , if not then document reference should say so .

I am trying to test it but i am getting findAll doesn't exist and not sure it is my code or it is not implemented

Comment: There's no Querydsl integration with Apache Cassandra yet.

Comment: I was struggling for the same. Thanks for the answer. Now, I will go for another alternative